# With "cargo cache" is it possible to remove dependencies which have not been used for a while?

Tags: caching, rust, rust-cargo

There is a command `cargo cache` which can be used to clean stuff from `.cargo` without just deleting the whole folder regularly (and thus having to re-download/build packages).

But either I don't get `cargo cache --help` right or this tool does not implement "remove all dependencies I don't need anymore based on all Cargo.toml which can be found".

Does it?

`cargo cache` takes some arguments which seem to provide a flexible way to get rid of stuff  you don't need anymore. Unfortunately on a closer look it doesn't seem to help me at all..

There is `clean-unref` but that seems to only work on a given `Cargo.toml` (what if you have a nested project with a couple of those?)

There is `trim` which removes older items until a max cache size limit is reached. But that way it keeps stuff I don't need and potentially removes stuff I still need. Correct?

There is `--autoclean` but that seems to remove everything?

There is `--keep-duplicate-crates <N>` but that too seems to work if you provide concrete directories.

There is `--remove-if-older-than` - but how do I know how old the oldest crates are I need? And it takes only "HH:MM:SS" or a date?!

And if you have a shared cache folder for different branches with possibly different `Cargo.toml` all those approaches seem to not work at all..

Is there a way to say: "Please remove all crates that haven't been used in the last  days"?

I'm close to just log access to `.cargo` using `inotify` and remove unneeded content manually, but that doesn't feel right..

Comment: The issue is that cargo doesn't really log the last time it uses a particular cache entry. You can potentially look at the atime of the files, though the accuracy isn't good in most cases.